# winrt::guid compile time?

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

base.h around line 189

```cpp
inline bool is_guid_equal(uint32_t const* const left, uint32_t const* const right) noexcept
{
    return left[0] == right[0] && left[1] == right[1] && left[2] == right[2] && left[3] == right[3];
}
```

It seems it could be easily `constexpr` ?

```cpp
constexpr
inline bool is_guid_equal(uint32_t const* const left, uint32_t const* const right) noexcept
{
    return left[0] == right[0] && left[1] == right[1] && left[2] == right[2] && left[3] == right[3];
}
```

After that is sorted `winrt::guid` should be easily turned to fully `constexpr` too.

Concrete question is: Is somebody thinking of that?

ps: wider context is C++20 "let's make everything constexpr" move...

Comment: This is referring to a well outdated implementation that ships as part of the Windows SDK. `is_equal_guid` does not exist in the generated *base.h* file when using the C++/WinRT NuGet package. If you can make a convincing point, why this (or `operator==`) should be `constexpr`, it's probably better to just open an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues).

Comment: `guid::operator==` is implemented using `memcmp` (which doesn't exist as a `constexpr` function). [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/463) explains, why it does.

Comment: SDK version is  "well outdated"? Are we allowed to ask why? Is this not crown jewel windows API?

Comment: C++/WinRT switched to NuGet-based deployment, so that it can progress without having to wait for the Windows SDK to ship a new version. If you are writing an application using C++/WinRT it is recommended to use the NuGet version instead, that generates - among others - *base.h*. I'm not aware of any commitment to ship an updated version of C++/WinRT with the Windows SDK.

Comment: Thanks  @IInspectable -- What is the role of windows sdk then?  I might have missed the memo ...

Comment: The Windows SDK ships the API surface. C++/WinRT is a C++ language projection for the Windows Runtime portion of the SDK.

Comment: Thus one needs both pieces to build the puzzle?  SDK and nuget latest version cpp win rt? I assume since cppwinrt is "headeronly" , app using it also requires modules from SDK ...

Comment: That is correct. The SDK provides the metadata (.winmd files) and import libraries. The C++/WinRT NuGet package contains the code generator (cppwinrt.exe) and Visual Studio build rules. cppwinrt.exe consumes .winmd files to generate the source and header files for use by client code. It does this for both the SDK-provided .winmd files as well as those .winmd files generated from user-authored IDL files. The build rules automate all required steps as well as specify the import and static libraries for the linker.

Comment: @IInspectable  excuse me asking do you work for Microsoft?

Comment: I have not and do not work for Microsoft.

Comment: Just finished short walk arround cppwinrt 2020 Q2 .... it seems to me its role, purpose and focus have been (drasticaly) changed since some times ago?  From "header only, C++17,  WINRT" astonishing work, that was supposed to finaly produce modern windows API and replacement for WIN32... it is now demoted to code generated by a tool? As just one of the "projections" namely C++.  While its original author has gone away to hapilly work on Rust winrt projection.  That was never projected as the future of cppwinrt way back in 2018 for example. Something does not add up here ....

Comment: There hasn't been any change really. C++/WinRT has always required tool support to transform [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) metadata into headers that can be consumed by a C++ compiler. Initially, Kenny Kerr published the generated headers through his personal GitHub repository. Later, the Windows SDK included the cppwinrt.exe binary, that was then published as source code. Likewise, Rust/WinRT will also - as far as I know - require [tool support](https://github.com/microsoft/winmd-rs) to bridge the gap between ECMA-335 metadata and Rust.